# Set "Access all my OneDrive files offline" via registry or script?

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

On Windows 8.1, in OneDrive's settings (OneDrive modern app > charms bar > options) there's an option to "access all my OneDrive files offline". Does anyone know if there's a non-manual way to set that? I've been hunting for a registry key but haven't found one.

[image]

Comment: You might want to word the question to request additional ways to set this option since "programming" questions are not on topic here at Superuser.  Since this is a good question ( except for the title ) I have provided an upvote to encourge you to improve the title and the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, Ramhound. It seems like every time I post I get nailed on some rule or another. And the rules vary per Stack Exchange site. Most people aren't as helpful as you were.

Comment: The rules are pretty much the same across the network.

Comment: Not in this case. On StackOverflow I can use the word "programmatically" without getting chastised.

Comment: I was only trying to help make your answer better and give you a chance to word your question to better explain what you actually wanted

Comment: Thanks for that, Ramhound. Sorry, didn't mean to accuse you of chastising me (recently had an unrelated experience on here). Anyway, I think we're good now.